# SELECT with 2 subqueries issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle, and I have next query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1;
```

which throws me as result `21932`, then I set previous query as subquery the next way:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table2 WHERE attr1 IN (SELECT attr1 FROM table1);
```

this throws me as result `10489`. So I want to delete rest of rows that are not within this set, before running `DELETE` sentence I wanted to check that number of rows was the right, with the next query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table1 WHERE attr1 NOT IN 
   (SELECT attr1 FROM table2 WHERE attr1 IN (SELECT attr1 FROM table1));
```

the number of rows should be `11443 (total - 10489)`, but the statement throws me `3743` rows, Why is this the result? How could I get the number of rows I want to delete?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are counting records in `table2` the `attr1` of which also exists in `table1`. That doesn't tell us anything about the records in `table2` that have no such match. Could be 1 record, could be a million records all with different `attr1`, could be a million records all with the same `attr1`, etc. So there is no math to tell us what your last query should result in.

... Or there is something about the two tables and `attr1` that you haven't told us.

Comment: Hm, and mathguy's guess about NULLs didn't apply either? `count(*)`, `count(attr1)`, and `count(distinct attr1)` give the same numbers per table?

Comment: Sorry the `attr1` is not unique in both tables, is only in `table2` but not in `table1`, I could notice run this statement `count(distinct attr1)`.

Comment: Okay then with `table1` having `attr1` = 1, 1, 2, 3, 3 and `table2` having `attr1` = 3, 4, 5. This gets you 5 for the first query, 1 for the second query, and 3 for the third one. 5 - 1 ≠ 3. It still holds true: there is no math telling you the result to expect for the third query based on the first two results.

Comment: got it, Thanks. This helps me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your nesting of selects in your where clause is probably the issue. To make it simpler, I'd say:

```
select count(*) from table1 t 
 where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2
                     where t2.attr1 = t.attr1)
```

Comment: Your statement throws me as result `3743`

Answer (score 1):

The discrepancy likely tells you something about `NULL` in `table1.attr1`, since `NULL` is neither `IN (...)` nor `NOT IN (...)`.

Try:  `select case when attr1 is null then 1 end as count_nulls from table1` - this will tell you directly how many nulls you have in `table1.attr1`.